# Unexpected output when running Bazel tests on Gitlab CI

Tags: kotlin, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, bazel

I have a Kotlin project with Bazel with some tests that I run with:

```
bazel run //my_service:tests
```

and this is the output when I run them in my machine:

```
Test run finished after 1195 ms
[         3 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         3 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         3 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         5 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         5 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         5 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

5 tests successful. So far, so good. But when tests are run from Gitlab CI, I get this output:

```
 Test run finished after 79 ms
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

As you see, no tests are found. Why?

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
default:
  image:
    name: l.gcr.io/google/bazel:2.2.0
    entrypoint: [""]

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bazel run //my_service:tests
```

I'm using Bazel 2.2.0 in both, local and Gitlab CI. Why am I not getting the same output?

The only difference is that on Gitlab CI, bazel is executed inside a container.

Comment: What OS are you working on locally? There might be some differences between Windows and Linux bazel (but it's a wild quess from my side). I would also try cloning a fresh copy locally and execute there `bazel run` so you are sure there are no cached/ignored settings.

Comment: I'm running on MacOS locally. I am going to test it with a fresh copy. Thank you